# $R[x_{i_1},…,x_{i_k}]\cong$ subring of $R[x_1,…,x_n]$, where $\{i_1,…,i_k\}\subseteq \{1,…,n\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, proof-explanation

**Definition:** Let $R$ be a ring with identity and let $R[x]$ denote the set of all sequences of elements of $R$ $(a_0,a_1,…)$ such that $a_i=0$ for all but a finite number of indices $i$. $x=(0,1_R,0,…)$ is called an indeterminate.

Let $R$ be a ring with identity and denote by $R[x_1,…,x_n]$ the set of all functions $f: N^n \to R$ such that $f(u)\neq 0$ for at most a finite number of elements $u$ of $N^n$. For all $1\leq i\leq n$,  $x_i:N^n\to R$ given by $x_i(0,…,1,…0)=1_R$ and $x_i(u)=0$ for $u\neq (0,…,1,…,0)$, where $1\in N$ is in $i$th coordinate.  $x_1,…,x_n$ are called indeterminate.

---

Context: page number $152$ of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra.

> If $R$ is any ring, then the map $R[x_1]\to R[x_1,…,x_n]$ defined by
> $$\sum_{i=0}^m a_ix_1^{i} \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^m a_ix_1^{i}x_2^0\cdots x_n^0 = \sum_{i=0}^m a_ix_1^{i} \in R[x_1,…,x_n]$$ is easily seen to be a monomorphism of rings. Similarly, for any subset $\{i_1,…,i_k\}$ of $\{1,2,…,n\}$ there is a monomorphism $R[x_{i_1},…,x_{i_k}]\to R[x_1,…,x_n]$. $R[x_{i_1},…,x_{i_k}]$ is usually identified with its isomorphic image and considered to be a subring of $R[x_1,…, x_n]$.

Throughout the problem, I will assume $R$ has identity because without identity $R[x_1,…,x_n]$ is a bit complicated ring with “innocent” notation but with lots of subtlety.

**Question:** Since notion of indeterminate is defined after the definition of ring of polynomials, $x_1\in R[x_1]$ is a function $N\to R$ such that $x_1(1)=1_R$ and $x_1(u)=0$ for $u\neq 1$. But $x_1$ is a function $N^n\to R$. **Which function $x_1$ is, $N\to R$ or $N^n\to R$?** In the former case, we can replace anything, let say $x$, in place of $x_1$. So we proved more general result. Which doesn’t feel right. In the latter case, elements $f\in R[x_1]$ are function $N^n\to R$. But elements of $R[x_1]$ are function $N\to R$ by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $R[x_1] \rightarrow R[x_1, ..., x_n]$ sends the map $N \rightarrow R$ called "$x_1$" to a map $N^n \rightarrow R$, also called "$x_1$". There is an abuse of notation here, since "$x_1$" refers to two different things.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am still feeling confuse. Can you please elaborate more in your answer, like what should have been the notation?

Comment: Perhaps less ambiguous notation would be to use "$x_i^n$" to designate the function $N^n \rightarrow R$ which maps $(0,...,1,....,0) \mapsto 1_R$ (with $1$ in the $i^{th}$ coordinate). Then your ring homomorphism $R[x_1^1] \rightarrow R[x_1^n, ..., x_n^n]$ would map $x_1^1$ to $x_1^n$.

Comment: For what it's worth, polynomial rings are characterized by a universal property. That basically means that anything you need to prove about them can be done just with the universal property, and you can forget the details of the construction. (In my opinion, that's more productive than stressing over these details.) The property is: for any $R$-algebra $S$ and any elements $s_1, ..., s_n$, there exists a unique $R$-algebra homomorphism $\phi : R[x_1, ..., x_n] \rightarrow S$ such that $\phi(x_i) = s_i$ for each $i$.